# Array of Errors is returning all mapped Errors React

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects that contains any errors that are on the site. I have created a function that maps over the errors and return an error message and link to the page with the error on it:

```
 const buildErrorLink = (pge, field) => {
    return (
      validationErrors &&
      validationErrors.map(err => (
        <>
          <p className="error">{err.message}</p>
          <h5 className="error-field-name">
            {pge ? (
              <a
                href="#"
                onClick={() => goToStep(pge, field, true)}
                className="review-page-error"
              >
                {err.fieldName}
              </a>
            ) : (
              <>{err.fieldName}</>
            )}
          </h5>
        </>
      ))
    );
 };
```

The goToStep() function just takes in a page and which field it is and that part works great.

The issue is in this function:

```
const validationError = () => {
    if (validationErrors) {
        if (validationErrors.filter(err => err.fieldName === 'name')) {
            return buildErrorLink(0, 'name');
        }
        if (
            validationErrors.filter(
                err => err.fieldName === 'state'
            )
        ) {
            return buildErrorLink(1, 'state');
        }
        if (
            validationErrors.filter(
                err => err.fieldName === 'city'
            )
        ) {
            return buildErrorLink(1, 'city');
        }
    }
    return buildErrorLink();
};
```

I should clarify that this is how I am returning validationError:

```
return (
   <div className="error">{validationError()}</div>
)
```

That displays all error messages but stops on the first one in the validationError function and passes that page to all the links. So my question is how to pass the correct page number to each link? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was I was mapping in the wrong place. I should have been mapping in the validationError function. My code ended up looking like this:

```
const buildErrorLink = (pge, fieldName, errMsg) => {
    return (
      <>
        <p className="error">{errMsg}</p>
        <h5 className="error-field-name">
          {pge ? (
            <a
              href="#"
              onClick={() => goToStep([pge], null, true)}
              className="error"
            >
              {fieldName}
            </a>
          ) : (
            <>{fieldName}</>
          )}
        </h5>
      </>
    );
  };

const validationError = () => {
    return (
      validationErrors &&
      validationErrors.map(err => {
        switch (err.fieldName) {
          case 'Name':
            return buildErrorLink(0, err.fieldName, err.message);
          case 'State':
            return buildErrorLink(1, err.fieldName, err.message);
          case 'City':
            return buildErrorLink(1, err.fieldName, err.message);
          default:
            return buildErrorLink();
        }
      })
    );
  };
```